# Will this template code do what's it's supposed to?

Tags: c++, templates

I want any `get_file_path(x)` call to be to the second function definition, in other words, the `std::shared_ptr<File>` specialization template code. As well as the `get_file_path<File>(t_name)` inside the first function definition.

```
    template<class T=File>
    std::shared_ptr<T> get_file_path (const std::string& t_name){
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(get_file_path<File>(t_name));
    }
    template<>
    std::shared_ptr<File> get_file_path (const std::string& t_name){
        auto it = rpath_asset_ht.find(t_name);
        if(it == rpath_asset_ht.end())return std::shared_ptr<File>();
        else return it->second;
    }
```

Will this code do that?

Comment: Have you tried using it? What happens when you do?

Comment: I haven't tried it. I shall in a second. Just wanted to know if theoretically it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that yes, the specialization template will get called for both cases.